# Cannot find any wireless networks - Networking service failing

Tags: networking, wireless, services

My netbook is running Ubuntu 10.04.03 LTS (lucid) and everything was working perfectly till yesterday. It was connected to the Internet through my Thompson router and when I woke up, my WI-FI was visible but it could not connect to it (kept prompting me for password which was obviously correct). I restarted the machine, and now it cannot see any wireless networks at all (I can see 3 wireless networks with my iPhone, including my own wi-fi).

Some things that I noticed:

1) The networking service does not seem to work, and I cannot do anything about it. For example the command:

```
sudo service networking start
```

gives:

```
networking stop/waiting
```

and the command:

```
sudo service networking stop(/restart)
```

gives:

```
stop(/restart): Unknown instance:
```

Correct me if I'm wrong but i think that this means that the service is in a weird "waiting" state and there is nothing that I can do to fix this.

2) I can see the wlan0 interface in the ifconfig + iwconfig commands.

3) The pan0 interface works without issues: I enabled internet tethering on my iPhone and the netbook connected to it via Bluetooth without issues.

I have no clue regarding to what is wrong. If you need any more information please let me know with a comment. Also, if there is like a way to reset everything regarding network interfaces to their default values I would like to know it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 2) I can see the wlan0 interface in the ifconfig + iwconfig commands

Ensure you have not disabled wireless by pressing some key combination on your particular netbook.

Comment: Wow! Apparently Fn+F6 was pressed! Never realized that there was a key combo to disable wireless networking :S